# Missing return UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am sure this question have been asked before but I can't find an answer that solves my problem with nested if-else and switch-case logic.
I have a `UITableView` with two sections, each sections has two custom cells.  That is it it. 4 cells.  But no matter what I do I get "Missing return in a function expected to return `UITableViewCell`"

**Question** How can I change this setup so that I get an else statement at the bottom that will satisfy swift logic?

Any help would be very much appreciated

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0{

        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            let cell0: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell0", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell0.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        break

        case 1:
            let cell1: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         break

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    if indexPath.section == 1{

        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            let cell10: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell10.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        break

        case 1:
            let cell11: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell11", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell11.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         break

        default:
            break

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to perform ...?

Comment: What do you mean by that.  I want a tableView with 2 sections, each with two cells.

Comment: @karlml write. return cell statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Haha! I love it!! Why do error messages even bother having messages at all...

Comment: @karlml you need to mention your tableview cell name in return statement... i think its SettingsCell.. so write  this line    return SettingsCell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Declare the cell  at the start of the method,
- assign a value to the cell depending on section and row number,
- throw a `fatalError()` in all cases that "should not occur",
- return the cell.

Also note that the `break` statements are not needed. The default
behavior in Swift is *not* to fall through to the next case.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: SettingsCell

    switch(indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell0", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        case 1:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section)")
        }
    case 1:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        case 1:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell11", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section)")

        }
    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected section \(indexPath.section)")

    }
    return cell
}
```

The `fatalError()` error function is marked as `@noreturn`, so the
compiler knows that program execution will not continue from the
default cases. (This also helps to find logic errors in the program.)

The compiler *verifies* that a value is assigned to `cell` in all
other cases.

The possibility to initialize a *constant* (`let cell ...`) in this
way is new in Swift 1.2.

---

**Alternatively,** you can create a cell and return it "immediately"
in each case:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch(indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell0", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            return cell

        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            return cell

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section)")
        }
    case 1:
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            return cell

        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell11", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            return cell

        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section)")

        }
    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected section \(indexPath.section)")
    }
}
```

Again, calling `fatalError()` solves  the "missing return expected" compiler 
error.

This pattern can be useful if there are different kinds of cells
(with different classes) created in each case.

Comment: This crash:  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on line: return cell

Comment: But it does compile now? – Have you verified that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a valid cell? Did you call `registerNib(..)` or `registerClass(...)` or have you defined prototype cells in the Storyboard (for all cell identifiers)?

Comment: All my prototype cells are custom..  should there be one that is empty?

Comment: @karlml: Are the prototype cells defined in the Storyboard? Have you assigned cell identifiers to each prototype cell (the same ones that you use in the code) ?

Comment: Yes they are, Yes I have

Comment: If I declare var cell: SettingsCell! I get no error but the app crash.   If I declare var cell: SettingsCell I get error "Variable 'cell' used before being initialized"

Comment: @karlml: Have you used the exact code from my answer? I do not get any compiler error for `var cell: SettingsCell `. – Perhaps you forgot to assign a value in one of the cases?

Answer (score 2):

You must return a cell, if the section is number 2 this methods won't be returning anything, well it's the case when u specify secitons more than two. Solution

- Second "if" will be "else" part
- Limit number of section

Answer (score 0):

You're missing in you method the **return statement**.

Example with return statement.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0{

        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell0", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        break

        case 1:
            let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         break

        default:
            let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
            var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as UITableViewCell
            break
        }
    }

    if indexPath.section == 1{

        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        break

        case 1:
            let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell11", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         break

        default:
             let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
             var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as UITableViewCell
            break

        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: you are returning the cell outside the if

Comment: "return cell" gives error "Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'"

Comment: @karlml you need to mention your tableview cell name in return statement... i think its SettingsCell.. so write this line return SettingsCell.

Comment: I edit it and put more information. In the default case you need to create a cell too. Even though it is not suppose to be never reached.

Comment: hmm, well "return cell" still gives error "Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'"

Answer (score 0):

you can use else if
like this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 0{

    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell0", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    break

    case 1:
        let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     break

    default:
        break
    }


    else if indexPath.section == 1{

    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    break

    case 1:
        let cell: SettingsCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell11", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     break

    default:
        break

    }
}
return cell
}
}
```

it may help you try it

Comment: else if indexPath.section == 1{ gives error "Expected expression"

Comment: ohh !! don`t worry , check your code again and check expressions. it will resolve your problem.