# how do i fix, variable used without initialization error?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, xcode6, initialization

i've implemented this switch statement within my code, and it worked perfectly fine until i restarted Xcode. Now it hits me with this error:

[image]

I clearly declared the variable in the above line of code. This was not a problem a couple of minutes ago. Is this just Xcode acting up?

Comment: The thing is: swift wants variables to have a state before the object is used. You declared a var vc of type UITableViewController only. Theres no value for that. And the switch statement may never get called. So we have a situation where vc might never have a value.   Try to put var vc:UITableViewController?

Comment: i set it to var vc:UITableViewController? and in turn set vc to vc! in my pushViewController method & it crashed @kandelvijaya

Comment: What do you expect if indexPath.row is not zero? You don't assign a view controller to vc in that case, of course that will crash.

Comment: i've ran the app in the debugger & in fact the indexPath.row of the cell i am testing is 0. @MartinR

Comment: if you have multiple sections then its a problem i guess.

Comment: How many sections do you have?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189505/missing-return-uitableviewcell/30190231#30190231 for a similar problem and how you can utilize fatalError() to tell the compiler about the "impossible" cases.

Comment: just 1 @kandelvijaya

Comment: i utilized fatalError() within my default: & it crashed as soon as i selected the 1st row in my table view @MartinR

Comment: do i need to return a value? or use an if statement? what am i missing @MartinR

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say your variable is undeclared. It says that it is not initialized. And it's right. I don't really know why did it work before. It shouldn't have.

The problem is that if `indexPath.row` is not equal to `0`, the `case 0` line will not be performed. The default case doesn't set any value to `vc`. So, you don't assign anything to `vc`, and yet you pass it into a function.

In order to fix it you should either set some default value to `vc` or set value in the `default` section.

Comment: i just set default value to vc = secondTableViewController & it crashed @FreeNickname

Comment: @RobertTillman, well, at least it compiles :) The crash is another problem and should probably be discussed in another question.

Comment: is there an issue within my switch statement? @FreeNickname

Comment: @RobertTillman, the `default` line is a bit unusual. The no-op blocks are usually implemented with a `break` (instead of `()`), but it looks fine to me. It's not the reason it crashes for sure.

Comment: i have just asked a MUCH MORE in-depth question with screenshots, be open to check it out @FreeNickname