# switch that checks NSIndexPath's row and section

Tags: swift, switch-statement, nsindexpath

I would like to set a switch statement that checks for a value if `NSIndexPath`. `NSIndexPath` is a class and it consists(among other things) of section and row (`indexPath.row, indexPath.section`)

this is how I would formulate an if statement to check for a row and a section at the same time:

```
if indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row == 0{
//do work
}
```

What is swift switch translation for this?

Comment: Perhaps useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189505/missing-return-uitableviewcell.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way (this works because NSIndexPaths themselves are equatable):

```
switch indexPath {
case NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0) : // do something
// other possible cases
default : break
}
```

Or you could just test against integers, using a tuple pattern:

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
case (0,0): // do something
// other cases
default : break
}
```

Another trick is to use `switch true` and the same condition you're already using:

```
switch true {
case indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 : // do something
// other cases
default : break
}
```

Personally, I would use *nested* `switch` statements where we test against `indexPath.section` on the outside and `indexPath.row` on the inside.

```
switch indexPath.section {
case 0:
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        // do something
    // other rows
    default:break
    }
// other sections (and _their_ rows)
default : break
}
```

Comment: I agree with your preferred nested approach, but the second could also be done as a `switch (indexPath.row, indexPath.section) { case(0,0): ...`

Comment: @MartinR D'Oh! I'm, like, Mister Tuple and I still dropped the ball on that one.

Comment: Second approach looks just great. Thank you!

Comment: @matt Thanks for sweet answer

Answer (score 20):

Just use `IndexPath`instead of `NSIndexPath` and do the following:

Tested in **Swift 3 and 4**:

```
switch indexPath {
case [0,0]: 
    // Do something
case [1,3]:
    // Do something else
default: break
}
```

The first integer is the `section`, the second one is the `row`.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that this method above isn't as powerful as the tuple matching method of matt's answer.

If you do it with a **tuple**, you can do something like this:

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
case (0...3, let row):
    // this matches sections 0 to 3 and every row + gives you a row variable
case (let section, 0..<2):
    // this matches all sections but only rows 0-1
case (4, _):
    // this matches section 4 and all possible rows, but ignores the row variable
    break
default: break
}
```

See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html for complete documentation of possible `switch` statement usages.

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative way is to combine `switch` with `if case`

```
switch indexPath.section {
case 0:
    if case 0 = indexPath.row {
        //do somthing
    } else if case 1 = indexPath.row  {
          //do somthing
        // other possible cases
    } else { // default
        //do somthing
    }
case 1:
// other possible cases
default:
    break
}
```