# Swift Variable Declaration and Initialize

Tags: swift

Is there a difference between how following bits of code work?

```
let x: Int = 4
```

and

```
let x: Int
x = 4
```

Comment: @KSigWyatt There's nothing wrong with initialising a `let` constant after its declaration, given that you cannot read it before initialising it. Why would "proper programming style" suggest making it a `var`?

Comment: @KSigWyatt: There are cases where you declare a constant first and later assign  a value to it (exactly once, but perhaps depending on some conditions). Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30190231/1187415.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one:

```
let x: Int = 4
```

creates a non-optional variable `x` and initialises it to `4`. `x` can be used without issue.

This one:

```
let x: Int
// Cannot do anything with x yet
x = 4
```

creates a non-optional variable `x` with **no defined value**. It cannot be used without first assigning it to a value, either directly (as in your example) or by the result of some other statement. If you do try and use it, you'll get a compile-time error.

Answer (score -1):

The only difference is that on the first one you are declaring a variable and assigning it at the same time, and the second one you declare it first and then assign it.

But there is no mayor difference.

Comment: ...no difference except that you're using two instructions vs. 1 by using the second style, which is marginally less efficient. Arguably, though, it makes your code less readable, which is an excellent argument against using the more verbose style.

Comment: Let's not split hairs. "No major difference" is not the same thing as a nuanced answer explaining what the *minor* differences actually are.